# How to prevent Select2 from selecting a highlighted option when pressing tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

In Select2, when you tab, it will automatically select an option if you tab while the option is highlighted.

If, for example, you select an option, then backspace to delete it, and have nothing in the textbox, the first option will still be highlighted, and so when you tab, it will select it.

I would like it so that it's possible for people to not have selected anything, and not have this happen.

Presumably, the best way is to alter how the behavior works when pressing Tab. (For example, never having it select the option, OR not having it select the option when the textbox is empty).

How would I do that?

```
<select id="example" multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
  <option value="JAN">January</option>
  <option value="FEB">February</option>
  <option value="MAR">March</option>
  <option value="APR">April</option>
  <option value="MAY">May</option>
  <option value="JUN">June</option>
  <option value="JUL">July</option>
  <option value="AUG">August</option>
  <option value="SEP">September</option>
  <option value="OCT">October</option>
  <option value="NOV">November</option>
  <option value="DEC">December</option>
</select>

$('#example').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select a month'
});
```

Example JSFiddle to test:
https://jsfiddle.net/NathanFriend/rLmztr2d/

Comment: so you want to disable tab when select2 has the focus?

Comment: I don't want to disable tab. I want tab to work, but I don't want it to select the highlighted option when the person presses tab (either when the textbox is empty, or even if there is text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by hooking into the `keydown` event on the search field, then checking if tab was pressed.

From there, you can save a `tabPressed` variable to `true`.

Then, you hook into the `select2:selecting` event, which is set off when it's going to select an option. From there, we check if tab was pressed and if the search field is an empty string - if it is, we simply cancel the event, close the select2 dropdown, and then find the next `input` and give it `focus()`

Here's the code:

```
<div>
  <input type="text">
</div>

<div>
  <select id="example" multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
      <option value="JAN">January</option>
      <option value="FEB">February</option>
      <option value="MAR">March</option>
      <option value="APR">April</option>
      <option value="MAY">May</option>
      <option value="JUN">June</option>
      <option value="JUL">July</option>
      <option value="AUG">August</option>
      <option value="SEP">September</option>
      <option value="OCT">October</option>
      <option value="NOV">November</option>
      <option value="DEC">December</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text">
</div>

$('#example').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select a month'
});

var tabPressed = false;

$('.select2-search__field').keydown((ev) => {
  if (ev.which == 9 ){
    var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
    tabPressed = true;
  }
});

$('#example').on("select2:selecting", function(e) { 
   if(tabPressed)
   {
     tabPressed = false;
     if($(this).parent().find('.select2-search__field').val() == '')
     {
         e.preventDefault();
       $("#example").select2("close");
       $(this).parent().next().find('input').focus();
     }
   }
});
```

Here's the jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/1e7vmwux/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could try to modify the tab effect when the focus is on select2 input:

```js
$('#example').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select a month'
});


$('.select2-search__field').keydown((ev) => {
  if (ev.which == 9 ){
   var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");e.which = 40;//code of downarrow  
   $('.select2-search__field').trigger(e)
   //$('.select2-search__field').val(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/js/select2.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<select id="example" multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="JAN">January</option>
    <option value="FEB">February</option>
    <option value="MAR">March</option>
    <option value="APR">April</option>
    <option value="MAY">May</option>
    <option value="JUN">June</option>
    <option value="JUL">July</option>
    <option value="AUG">August</option>
    <option value="SEP">September</option>
    <option value="OCT">October</option>
    <option value="NOV">November</option>
    <option value="DEC">December</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I still want the tab functionality to work, however, to not have select2 select the element that is being highlighted when tab is pressed.

Comment: ok but on select2, its the default functionality of tab to select highlighted  , what functionality you want for tab? tab is  always functional.but its default functionality is changed only for  this select2 item..as you asked

Comment: i have modified my code to show you a sample to add a new fucntionality for tab. whe ntab is pressed, it triggers the key downarrow, but you can put change this action if you want another..

Comment: this wasn't what I wanted to do, but it helped me to understand how to achieve what I wanted to do. I've posted my answer if you'd like to check it out. Thanks